# set css to parent child size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following css and html, and I am trying to get my `<div>` following the `<img>` to inherit the *width* and *height* of the `<img>`. The following `<div>` is meant to be an overlay. Is there a way for the `<div>` to obtain the true *width* and *height* of the `<img>`?

I have not tried javascript yet and would prefer to do it purely with CSS, but if I must I will use javascript. I am not using jQuery at all and do not plan to.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div_1">
  <div><img src=""/><div></div></div>
  <div><img src=""/><div></div></div>
  ....
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div_1 > div {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}

.div_1 > div > img {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
}

.div_1 > div > div {
  width: .div_1.div.img.width;
  height: .div_1.div.img.height;
}
```

Comment: in css you can't "inherit" from a sibling, but you can inherit from a parent. make the container div some size, then force the image and child div to be that size as well.

Comment: Try some JS to get the height and width of the image then set style.width and style.height of the div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting to inner `div`'s position to `absolute` and the outer's to `relative`:

```css
.div_1 > div {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
.div_1 > div > img {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  display: block; /* remove default spacing from bottom of <img> */
}
.div_1 > div > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Not necessary... */

.div_1 > div > div:after {
  content: "Ummmmm, bacon!";
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="div_1">
  <div>
    <img src="http://baconmockup.com/200/200" />
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://baconmockup.com/200/200" />
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```